# the example of a set which its Kuratowski measure is nonzero but the closure of it isn;t compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let D be a bounded subset of a metric space (M,d). If D —
n
U Pi, then we say that P — {P\,-  ,Pn} is a finite partition of D, and we set
t = l
||P|| = sup{diam(Pi) :i = 1,··- ,n}.
The Kuratowski measure of noncompactness x(D) of D is defined as follows:
x(D) = inf{||P|| : P is a finite partition of D).

by the definition above I know that x(D) =0 if and only if the closure of D  is compact,but I am searching for an example of a set D which x(D) is nonzero and the closure of D is not compact.

Comment: You need to make this question more readable, the mathematical expressions look like nonsense.

Comment: Take the unit ball of $\ell^p$ space of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

See, for example, Theorem 1.1.6 in R. Akhmerov, M. Kamenskii, A. Potapov, B Sadovskii, Measures of Noncompactness and Condensing Operators, Birkhauser, Basel, 1992:
Let В be the unit ball in E. Then  a(B)= χ(Β) = 0 if Ε is  finite-dimensional, and a(B) = 2, χ(Β) = 1 in the opposite case, where  a(.) is Kuratowski measure of noncompactness and χ(.) is Hausdorff measure of noncompactness.